# Repeating background vertically with space

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have an image with a dotted line that I want to have as a background in a textarea. The image is of 3px height and 620px width, and what I want is to repeat it vertically with a space of 8px between every line. The code below repeats the background but without the distance. How could this be done (if it's possible)?

```css
textarea#story {
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-image: url(../img/underline.png);
  background-position: 5px 20px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Below is what I want. Right now the space between the lines is missing:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why don't you just add space in the background image itself? Look's like a much easier solution to me

Comment: @koningdavid: I want the possibility to change the distance programmatically by several reasons, but if that's not possible I guess I have to go with that.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes there is no way to set margin/padding on background images. Maybe you can create different asset's and replace the background image if you wan't to change the space

Comment: No you can't. also, dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577158/css-how-to-control-the-gap-between-background-image-and-container

Comment: I agree with @koningdavid.. Maybe it's possible to make a canvas dotted line and there spaces big as you want, but I don't think it's possible to make canvas on background. I'm not sure about this X_X.. You could try making div behind [some fun with x-index maybe] that text and fill it with that image pragmatically with padding as u wish :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, this is impossible. You will have to add the space in the image itself.